# Is it possible to determine the type of a class at instantiation or convert the type afterwards without casting?

Tags: vb.net, class, type-conversion, typeconverter

For example: I have some classes that all inherit from the same class.

```vb
Public Class MasterClass
    ' content
End Class

Public Class ClassA
  Inherits MasterClass
    'content
End Class
Public Class ClassB
  Inherits MasterClass
    'content
End Class
Public Class ClassC
  Inherits MasterClass
    'content
End Class
```

And I want decide on runtime which one I need. Then I can do something like this:

```vb
Private myInstance As MasterClass
If conditionA Then
    myInstance = New ClassA
ElseIf conditionB Then
    myInstance = New ClassB
Else
    myInstance = New ClassC
End
```

But it can get quite long, and I still have to cast it evertime I use it.

I can assing a type to a variable, but I don't know how to use that type to create a new instance of that type..

```vb
Dim storedType As Type = GetType(ClassA)
Dim someInstance = New storedType 'Does not work
```

Is there a better way? Can you change the type of a variable at runtime?

Comment: The creation part is a "factory".  And yes, it can get quite long if you need to hard-code it.  Depending on what you're trying to do, there may be reflection-based approaches that would make it so you don't need to add code to the factory for every possible class it could return (this may even be necessary if you want to have some sort of plugin support where the plugins would be released from third parties or on a different cadence from your main program).

Answer (score 1):

> I still have to cast it evertime I use it.

The idea around polymorphism and inheritance is that you *don't* have to cast them to use them. You can write things in such a way that the master class has all the functions etc that you need (whether or not they do anything) and then you call things as if you were just dealing with the master class but, because each child implements a different behavior, the end result is different - your program might not even know (if the child implementation came from a third party dll) what is going on but *it doesn't matter*

> Can you change the type of a variable at runtime?

Sure, but you have to use it how it appears. Long chains of "if my object is an instance of x then cast my object as x and use method X1, else if my object is a y then cast as y and call y1" are not polymorphic/not leveraging inheritance principles properly - you're supposed to call myobject.whatever, and if my object is an x, then x1 happens and if it's a y then y1 happens

> I want decide on runtime which one I need

But you don't have to do that in the class that knows about class a/b/c - each of class a/b/c can do that and hence become self contained. You can have all your instances in an array of the parent type, and visit each one asking them if they handle the condition and use the one that says it can

Consider a slightly better real world example than this artificial class a/b/c trope:

You are tasked with writing an app that can download an image (png, jpg or gif) from somewhere (http or ftp or disk location), rotate it and upload it to somewhere else

You decide to have an ImageRotator parent that specifies a CanHandle function and a Rotate function. It has 3 subclasses, one that handles jpg, one that rotates gif and one that does png. When presented with a PNG filename the JpgRotator says No when asked if it can handle it etc.

Separately you have a FileMover parent that CanHandle and has Download/Upload functions. Again, the parent doesn't implement these at all. The three subclasses implement the ability up/down an http, an ftp and a disk location

You create an instance of each rotator and put it into an array of ImageRotator type. You also create an instance of each mover onto an array that is a FileMover parent type.

Your user specifies a jpg in a http url, and to store it in a disk location at the end. You loop your FileMovers and ask each if they support the location the user provided. The http mover says yes, you invoke its download to a temp path. Then you pass he path to each rotator, the jpg rotator says yes, you call rotate. Finally, you look for another mover that can handle an output path of local disk...

Someone decides to extend your program with a plug-in dll that adds he ability to put files in and out of a db, and support tiff images.. ignoring the magic of how instances of their classes come to be in your arrays, you can see that your program can now move these new locations and types because the logic for whether they handle db/tiff is not a part of your code.. your code just treats everything consistently

Comment: Can you then at least make the declaration easier? There are like over 20 child classes and I already have their types in a list.

Comment: Er, yes.. you can use an IOC container/DI but honestly.. it's 20 lines of code that you need do only once.. just do it! ps, check the edit to my answer

Answer (score 1):

In this case ***Interfaces*** are the best choice

```
Interface ABC
    Property Text As String
    Property Value As Integer
End Interface
Public Class MasterClass

End Class

Public Class ClassA
    Inherits MasterClass : Implements ABC
    Property Mystr As String Implements ABC.Text
    Property Sum As Integer Implements ABC.Value
End Class
Public Class ClassB
    Inherits MasterClass : Implements ABC
    Property MyText As String Implements ABC.Text
    Property Value As Integer Implements ABC.Value
End Class
Public Class ClassC
    Inherits MasterClass : Implements ABC
    Property str As String Implements ABC.Text
    Property Value As Integer Implements ABC.Value
End Class
```

usage

```
Dim myABC As ABC
If conditionA Then
    myABC = New ClassA
ElseIf conditionB Then
    myABC = New ClassB
Else
    myABC = New ClassC
End If
myABC.Text = "Interface"
```